# How to print and control reset printer programmatically vs2008 C# windows Applications

Tags: visual-studio-2008

i use printer to print on some rows and columns pre made on papers so i want to control default printer settings  to some settings programmatically using C# windows Applications 
some help  me please . thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `PrinterSettings` class to change printer settings. You can find more information about that [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1x1919zd.aspx).
If you need to set the default printer I don't know of any .Net way of doing it but you could call the `SetDefaultPrinter` API function via PInvoke as described [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/winspool/setdefaultprinter.html?diff=y).